# Prove/disprove: Let $g\in G$ satisfy $o(g) = n$ and $g^m\in H$, where$ (n,m)=1.$ Then $g \in H.$

Tags: group-theory

Here's a homework question:

Prove or disprove: Let $g \in G$ satisfy $o(g)=n$ and $g^m \in H$ where $(n,m)=1$. Then $g\in H$.

I've tested a couple of examples and couldn't find a counterexample. Any hints for a proof?

Comment: What is $n$? the order of $G$?

Comment: n is the order of g

Comment: What results do you know?

Answer (score 4):

Since $gcd(m,n)=1$ we can find $r,s\in \mathbb Z$ such that $rm+ns=1$. Now $x=x^1=x^{rm+ns}=x^{rm}x^{ns}=x^{rm}\in H$

Answer (score 1):

The claim is true. This is because $m$ has a multtiplicative inverse $\bmod n$, we call it $a$.

If $g^m\in H$ then $(g^m)^a\in H$. But $(g^m)^a=g^{am}$ but $am\equiv 1 \bmod n$ so $am=nk+1$.

So $g^{am}=g^{nk+1}=(g^n)^kg^{1}=eg$ since the order of $g$ is $n$.

So $g^{am}=g$ is an element of $H$ also, which is what we wished to prove.

Answer (score 0):

In $\,G/H\!:$ $\,\ \bar g^n\!=1=\bar g^m$ $\Rightarrow$ $\, o(\bar g)\mid n,m$ $\overset{(n,m)\,=\,1}\Longrightarrow$ $o(\bar g)=1\, $ $\Rightarrow$ $\, \bar g = 1\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,g\in H$

Comment: Bill, $H$ does not have to be normal, so $G/H$ could be meaningless ...

Comment: @NickyHekster It is not stated what $G$ or $H$ is in the OP, so took the liberty to interpret in a way that sheds light on the essence of the matter. If you unwind the above you get a general argument: it amounts to the fact that $\,S = \{k\in \Bbb Z : g^k \in H\}$ is closed under subtraction, so a subgroup of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ so $\, S = d \Bbb Z,\,$ so $\, g^m,g^n\in H\,\Rightarrow\, m,n\in S\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid m,n\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid (m,n)=1,\,$ so $\,d=1\in S\,\Rightarrow\, g\in H.\ \ $

Comment: Or, equivalently, $\,S\subset \Bbb Z\,$ is closed under subtraction so $\,S\,$ is closed under gcd, therefore $\,m,n\in S\,\Rightarrow\,(m,n)=1\in S\,\Rightarrow\,g\in H.\ \ $